# Should I lock a datatable in multithread paradigm?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching

In a project of windows services (C# .Net Platform), I need a suggestion.
In the project I have class named Cache, in which I keep some data that I need frequently. There is a thread that updates cache after each 30 minutes. Where as there are multiple threads which use cache data.
In the cache class, there are getter and setter functions which are used by user threads and cache updater thread respectively. No one uses data objects like tables directly, because they are private members.
From the above context, do you think I should use locking functionality in the cache class?

Comment: is the cache a singleton? are there threads with higher priority than the updater thread?

Comment: Yeah, the cache is singleton.

Comment: Sidenote - there are libraries for caching that does exactly the same - such as Microsoft Enterprise Library. Why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: some times we need too much customization, which ultimately leads to reinvent the wheel but in some different pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effects of not using locks when writing to a shared memory location (like cache) really depend on the application. If the code was used in banking software the results could be catastrophic.

As a rule o thumb - when multiple threads access the same location, even if only one tread writes and all the other read, you should use locks (for write operation). What can happen is that one thread will start reading data, get swiped out by the updater thread; So it'll potentially end up using a mixture of old and new data. If that really as an impact depends on the application and how sensible it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Key Point:**  If you don't lock on the reads there's a chance your read won't see the changes.  A lock will force your read code to get values from main memory rather than pulling data from a cache or register.  To avoid actually locking you could use Thread.MemoryBarrier(), which will do the same job without overhead of actually locking anything.

**Minor Points:**  Using lock would prevent a read from getting half old data and half new data.  If you are reading more than one field, I recommend it.  If you are really clever, you could keep all the data in an immutable object and return that object to anyone calling the getter and so avoid the need for a lock.  (When new data comes in, you create a new immutable object, then replace the old with the new in one go.  Use a lock for the actual write, *or*, if you're still feeling really clever, make the field referencing the object volatile.)

Also:  when your getter is called, remember it's running on many other threads.  There's a tendency to think that once something is running the Cache class's code it's all on the same thread, and it's *not*.

Comment: What do you  suggest whether I should lock the cached object while updating it in setter, or reading it in getter? I think locking in setter will be better!

Comment: @NadeemJamali:  Both!  My answer focused on the read problem; I was just assuming a write lock was necessary.  There are probably ways to avoid locking here, but you've got to do other things (like immutable objects and volatile fields), and you've got to know what you're doing.  The key point I was trying to make is that without locking your reads, particularly if they occur within seconds of a write, may not see the changes at all.  It's possible they would only see the changes from several updates back, or even no updates at all.